# "I finally was able" or "I was finally able"?

Tags: verbs, adverbs, word-order, adverb-position

Is one form wrong or more correct than the other? Or do they have different meanings?

I'm a non-native speaker trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between *finally was* and *was finally* is the adverb/verb order. Here, your verb is "was", a form of *to be* and the adverb is *finally*. There is a good guide on [adverb placement](http://esl.about.com/library/grammar/blgr_adverbs_frequency.htm), and some listed rules are:

> 1. If the sentence has one verb in it (e.g. no auxiliary verb) we usually put the adverb in the middle of the sentence, i.e. after the subject and before the verb
> 2. The adverb usually comes after the verb "be" (there are several cases in which this is broken)
> 3. If the sentence has more than one verb in it (e.g. auxiliary verb) we usually put the adverb after the first part of the verb

Because your sentence uses *was*, a past tense form of *to be*, the second rule applies: The proper word order is:

> I was finally able

Note that if you do happen to invert the adverb/verb order, you will be understood in most cases but it won't sound right to a native ear.

Comment: "I was finally able" sounds more natural unless there's emphasis on "finally". But "I **finally** was able to ..." sounds perfectly natural if one wishes to heavily stress that a long time was needed.

Comment: The rules cited here appear to be simplified ones for ESL (which are good ones for the OP, since he is not a native speaker). In this case, you can certainly put *finally* in either place. @David Schwartz's comment is correct.